# Display toplevel tk at the begining of a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application where I want to display a progress bar during calcul.
So, there is a button on my app to run a function and also display the progress bar, but the child window only appears at the end of the calcul.

To reproduce this you can try the code below :

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk as ttk


class MainApplication:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button_start = tk.Button(
            self.master, text='Begin', command=self.upload_button)
        self.button_start.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)


    def upload_button(self):
        newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        newWindow.title("Chargment...")
        newWindow.geometry("400x70")
        # A Label widget to show in toplevel
        ttk.Label(newWindow, text="Please wait...").pack()
        pb = ttk.Progressbar(newWindow, length=300)
        pb.pack()
        pb.start(10)
        for i in range(90000):
            print(i)


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("my title")
MainApplication(window)
window.mainloop()
```

**EDIT**

I have tried to use threading and after to resolve my problem but i get stuck. I don't know how to replace the after method by some calcul in python using pandas. I can't just put one value for the delay in the after method because the delay could be different if the final user work on a small table or a bigger one.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading
import time
from tkinter import messagebox
from itertools import count


class GIFLabel(tk.Label):
    """a label that displays images, and plays them if they are gifs"""
    def load(self, im):
        if isinstance(im, str):
            im = Image.open(im)
        self.loc = 0
        self.frames = []
    try:
        for i in count(1):
            self.frames.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(im.copy().resize((20,20))))
            im.seek(i)
    except EOFError:
        pass

    try:
        self.delay = im.info['duration']
    except:
        self.delay = 100

    if len(self.frames) == 1:
        self.config(image=self.frames[0])
    else:
        self.next_frame()

def unload(self):
    self.config(image="")
    self.frames = None

def next_frame(self):
    if self.frames:
        self.loc += 1
        self.loc %= len(self.frames)
        self.config(image=self.frames[self.loc])
        self.after(self.delay, self.next_frame)





class MainApplication:

def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.button_start = tk.Button(self.master, text='Begin', command=self.upload_button)
    self.button_start.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
    self.loading = GIFLabel(self.master)
    self.loading.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7)
    self.loading.load('loading.gif')
    
def wait_generate(self):
    if self.update_Thread.isAlive():
        self.master.after(500, self.wait_generate)

    else:
        self.loading.unload()
        self.loading.load('ok.png')
        messagebox.showinfo("Complete", "Report generation completed!")
        


def upload_button(self):
    self.update_Thread = threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(5,))
    self.update_Thread.start()
    self.wait_generate()


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("my title")
MainApplication(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to use [`after`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method) method instead of using `for` or `while` loops

Answer (score 1):

When you run through your `for` loop, the tkinter window doesn't get a chance to automatically update (normally through `mainloop`).

There are two options

1. Run the for loop in a separate Thread (you can't run tkinter in a separate thread though)
2. Manually update the window in your `for` loop

You can research how to use threads, but the simplest option here is to include either of the following in your `for` loop:

`self.master.update()` or `newWindow.update()`

This manually updates the window, meaning that the progress bar can be updated and become visible.

It should look like this:

```py
for i in range(90000):
    print(i)

    # you can use
    self.master.update()
    # or
    newWindow.update()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your solution with the `newWindow.update()` works perfectly for this use case. Sadly, my app is a bit more complex and I have few differents loops and others calcul so this solution doesn't work. I will search informtion on threads !